# Array in Array : How to store array data in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example I have brunch of data like below:

HTML:

```
<p class="test-tag">abc+dd</p><p class="test-tag">gf+sx</p>
```

and store in JavaScript in array form

```
var text = ["abc+dd","gf+sx"];
```

And I must return an array like below:

```
var res = [["abc", "dd"],["gf", "sx"]];
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to best generate the P tag from the give array RES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map over your array and use split:

[Example JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kogahe/1/edit?js,console)

```
var text = ["abc+dd","gf+sx"];

var array = text.map(function(v) {
  return v.split('+');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like below should work..

```
var finalArr = [];
$('.test-tag').each (function (){
var value = $(this).text;
var subArr = value. map(function (b){
    return b.split('+');
  })
finalArr. push(subArr);
})
```